# referencing opaque types with python ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm using a 3rd party C library that defines an opaque type:

```
    foo_t
```

And uses pointers to this type in its functions:

```
    void foo_init(foo_t *foo);
```

Typical usage would be allocating a foo_t on the stack and passing a reference:

```
  {
    foo_t foo;

    foo_init(&foo);
    ...
  }
```

How do I call `foo_init()` with ctypes without knowing what constitutes a `foo_t`?

I think if I knew `sizeof(foo_t)` I could create a buffer of that size and cast, but is it possible to get the size with ctypes?

I could write a one-liner C program:

```
    printf("sizeof(foo_t) = %zu\n", sizeof(foo_t));
```

and hard-code that value into my python, but that would get ugly in a hurry: I'd have to touch my python source with every upgrade to the library.

A slightly cleaner way would be to write a python c-ext to export the size value, but that too would require a recompile with every library upgrade.

Does anyone have a recipe for using ctypes with such opaque types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the simplest solution...

Create a C file, say, foosizes.c:

```
    size_t SIZEOF_FOO = sizeof(foo_t);
```

And compile it into a shared object, `foosizes.so`.  Then in a python script:

```
    from ctypes import *
    foosizeslib = CDLL('foosizes.so')
    sizeof_foo = c_ulong.in_dll(foosizeslib, 'SIZEOF_FOO')
```

I can then create a buffer of the appropriate size and pass it to functions, by reference, as a pointer to the opaque type.  So far, so good.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the size with ctypes as C does not support runtime reflection, as no metadata about types is stored in the compiled binary as is done with Java or C#/.Net.

As you said, one way to get the size is create a simple C program that includes the header that defines the type and then use the sizeof operator to print out the size.  Taking that a step further you could utilize a [C compiler written in Python](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/31948-c-compiler-written-python) to compile and execute your C code to get the size when your Python code is executed.  You might even be able to get it without needing to actually execute the result by walking the data structures provided by the compiler.

That said, are you certain you need to create the memory yourself?  Frequently C libraries provide a method to create an opaque type that their other functions operate on.  **Update**: from the comments it is certain that the memory must be allocated by the caller.

Comment: In this library there is no function to create the type.  You have to allocate it on the stack or use malloc.

Comment: As for writing a small c-program, or python c-ext to get the size, yes, I suggest that very solution in my original post...I'm just wondering if others have a different recipe.

Comment: Well you could embed a C compiler written in Python into your Python. Answer updated to include that.